# Undefined offset in capabilities.php when trying to edit a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just moved my multisite from one server to another, changing the site domain along the way. I followed the steps for moving a multisite described in the WP Codex and after some fiddling about everything seems to work as expected now... apart from one thing:

Whenever I try to create a new page/post or edit or update an existing page/post I get the following debug message and I am not redirected to the page/post edit page:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /x/y/z/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1067

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /x/y/z/wp-includes/capabilities.php:1067) in /x/y/z/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

I have already searched the Wordpress forums, Google and of course Stackoverflow but none of the offered solutions seemed to work.

Interestingly, the URL I am redirected to when hitting the Publish/Update button seems to lack all arguments:

```
http://mysite.com/wp-admin/post.php
```

Another interesting thing is that the updates I do are saved and stored in the database. So when I visit the actual site any updates are reflected, but somehow the update process on the admin site is broken. I'm kinda stuck here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is not the software that would really care about such programing errors as undefined indexes. You have to run it with at least notices off, and I recomend turning off outputting of errors completely. To do it, consult your server administrator. There might be already some setting in control panel for it.